# Using panels in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i created a textbox, a button and a panel in a page. So my aim is to create links which will be put inside a panel. However, it turns out that every time i add another one, it seems to replace the previously created link. Is there a way to just add the links, not replacing previously created links? I really don't have a background that much in ASP.

This is the code I researched.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles   Button1.Click
    Dim link As New HyperLink()
    Dim ltr As New Literal()

    link.Text = TextBox1.Text
    link.NavigateUrl = "Default.aspx?field1=" + TextBox2.Text + " "
    ltr.Text = "<br/>"

    Panel1.Controls.Add(ltr)
    Panel1.Controls.Add(link)
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Look at `<asp:PlaceHolder>`... then you can add new controls to the `.Controls` collection

Comment: every time you click on the button, the page gets posted back and the previously dynamic loaded controls are not retained

Comment: i tried <asp:PlaceHolder> but i got same result. Is there a way to retain the links even if the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Rex, when post back occurs dynamically controls will be removed from the page until we retain them in Init Event.

While adding controls to PlaceHolder, save the same data like ID, Text..etc. in a object like session variable and retrieve the same data in Page Init event and add to the place holder.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Retrieve from session variable and add the same data to the place holder.
}
```